# Is a Function Object a built in class type in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, object

When I use `help(__builtins__)` I get a massive amount of information, including the  built in classes. In this list, although, there is no class "Function", but when I define a function:

```
def Function():
    pass
print(type(Function))
```

and print it, I get:

> <class 'function'>

But since it didn't came for built in and i didn't created a new class, where does it come from?

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) - in the 3.2 section search for or scroll down to  `callable types`.

Comment: The class of functions is not something a programmer often actually needs, so it's not put in the global namespace.  Do `import types`, then use `types.FunctionType` if you actually need to refer to this class.